# how to order the stacked bar using plotnine

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, plotnine

I have the following `dataframe`

```
import pandas as pd
from plotnine import *

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'variable': ['gender', 'gender', 'age', 'age', 'age', 'income', 'income', 'income', 'income'],
    'category': ['Female', 'Male', '1-24', '25-54', '55+', 'Lo', 'Lo-Med', 'Med', 'High'],
    'value': [60, 40, 50, 30, 20, 10, 25, 25, 40],
})
df['variable'] = pd.Categorical(df['variable'], categories=['gender', 'age', 'income'])
```

An I am using the following code to get the stacked bar plot

```
(ggplot(df, aes(x='variable', y='value', fill='category'))
 + geom_col()
)
```

The above code was taken from [here](https://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/plotnine.geoms.geom_col.html)

How can I change the order in each of the categories. E.g. I want the `age` `1-24` to be at the bottom of the `age` stacked bar

Answer (score 3):

You can specify which column order will be stacked by using `pd.Categorical` function with `ordered=True`. This attribute ensures the category order will be preserved the way you want during the plotting process:

```
# Categories are shown in a top-down order, 
# so you must reverse 'ages' order to be shown in bottom-up fashion
cat_order = ['Female', 'Male', '55+', '25-54', '1-24', 'Lo', 'Lo-Med', 'Med', 'High']

df['category'] = pd.Categorical(df['category'], categories=cat_order, ordered=True)
```